# AWS RDS Slow Insert

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, bulkinsert

I have a question regarding the insert of rows in RDS.
I am inserting in that example 301119 records in 1 table.

Here my log on those inserts batch :

```
Amazon : 

2014-09-05 12:12:47,245 - Processing 30119 users 
2014-09-05 12:15:01,508 - 5000 users updated in transaction 
2014-09-05 12:17:29,672 - 10000 users updated in transaction 
2014-09-05 12:19:30,499 - 15000 users updated in transaction 
2014-09-05 12:21:38,866 - 20000 users updated in transaction 
2014-09-05 12:23:26,659 - 25000 users updated in transaction 
2014-09-05 12:25:16,727 - 30000 users updated in transaction 
2014-09-05 12:25:19,376 - 30119 users updated in transaction - DONE 
2014-09-05 12:25:19,379 - Process completed in **752134** ms 


Local : 

2014-09-05 12:33:20,767 - Processing 30119 users 
2014-09-05 12:33:39,692 - 5000 users updated in transaction 
2014-09-05 12:33:50,949 - 10000 users updated in transaction 
2014-09-05 12:33:59,476 - 15000 users updated in transaction 
2014-09-05 12:34:06,962 - 20000 users updated in transaction 
2014-09-05 12:34:14,874 - 25000 users updated in transaction 
2014-09-05 12:34:22,945 - 30000 users updated in transaction 
2014-09-05 12:34:23,111 - 30119 users updated in transaction - DONE 
2014-09-05 12:34:23,112 - Process completed in **62345** ms
```

The query is a straightforward batch insert in 1 table.

My local is not very fast and those results are quite weird ... it takes 12 times more to run the same inserts in AWS ... So, there is something wrong ... It that a configuration problem or other ?

Some pointers would be very welcome :) :)

Thank you !

Comment: What instance type do you have? If you have a micro instance it is not really surprising.

Comment: Actually we upgraded to a X-LARGE with 5000 of IOPS , and it is slow, now instead of being 12 times slower than my local, it is 10 times slower ... very disturbing :-/

Comment: What process is inserting the data? Is that process running in the same Availability Zone as the RDS instance?

Comment: Thank you for your help David, both are on west-2b. The process that insert the data is done by Spring framework (  batchUpdate() query )

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, I figured it out ! After searching and tweaking the configuration, we were around 300 Inserts per Seconds, we disabled the innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit (1 -> 0) and the sync_binlog (1 -> 0), and we went up to 1500-2000 Inserts per Second !!
Since we are ok losing the last transaction / commit if the db crash so we went with and it is now blazing fast !!

Hopes it helps some of other people that are having the same issue !

Comment: could you direct how you did that

Comment: You have to go to the AWS Console . In it you find your instances and modify those settings.

Comment: @julien is it safe to change sync_binlog to 0? after changing I need to restart the instance?
I ask because I do not know very well and I have the same problem. all my inserts and updates are slow.

Comment: Yes we have been running with that setting for a while now and we are doing good. I believe it is a hot value so no restart needed - Not 100% sure though :)

Comment: Wow we are seeing the exactly thing. Super slow performance of an expensive RDS. We see only around 80 basic/small inserts per second into a very small table. We are using PHP laravel. I tried forcing 1000 row at a time batches via transaction begin/commit and didn't help. This innodb log flush and binlog could be what we need!

Comment: Hmm ok, not seeing any perceivable improvement in speed after setting ` innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit (1 -> 0)` and `sync_binlog (1 -> 0)` :/ still investigating...

Answer (score 3):

AWS limits the IOPS and Burst Performance of RDS sometimes.

["Provisioning less than 100 GB of General Purpose (SSD) storage for high throughput workloads could result in higher latencies upon exhaustion of the initial General Purpose (SSD) IO credit balance"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html#Concepts.Storage.GeneralSSD)